# Dynamic stamp with input fields

Tags: javascript, pdf, dynamic, stamp

I need to create a dynamic stamp for my company. This should contain form fields for input.
Is this possible in any way?

Thank you for your efforts

Comment: It's possible but non-trivial. Do you have any JavaScript programming experience? If not, you'll likely need to hire someone.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but does require at least intermediate level of knowledge of Acrobat JavaScript.

For learning "all about stamps", I strongly recommend the book "All about PDF Stamps in Acrobat and Paperless Workflows" by Thom Parker (available from Amazon as hardcopy and in Kindle format).

Comment: I have basic knowledge of javascript, but more to do customisation, not for own programming. 
so it's not possible with a copy paste script?

Comment: The mentioned book (and maybe the samples from pdfscripting.com (by Thom Parker)) should help. Depending on your requirement, you can adapt existing stamps, but, it does really depend.